# Get A Token From URL

Tags: javascript, android-studio, authorization, token, get-request

I have a url for a stream in my app on android studio. However this stream requires token verification so I need a way to send a GET request to a url on my server where the token is printed.

I then need to add this token to my stream url and start the activity.

How would I go about doing this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Token as in Authentication token for example?

Comment: Exactly it’s a token that allows the client access to my server to play the stream.

Comment: The standard way to do it is to put your token in the request's header. For example with a header `Authorization: your-token-value-here`. Then on the server you look up that header and verify it

Comment: Unfortunately I am new to android studio so I am unsure how to do this. My token is regenerated whenever the page is refreshed.

Comment: when you log into your app, do you receive a token?

Comment: No my app is a tv streaming app that gets its data from my database. However most of my streaming urls require token authentication to play. The app however doesn’t have this functionality. Therefore I wish to make the app go to the token url, get the token and add it to the stream url and play.

Comment: Ok, then you GET your token, you store somewhere in your app. After that to stream a resource you provide the URL + you put the `Authorization` header in the request. You can also put it in the URL itself but you should probably put it in the headers as it is the standard way

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. However I am unsure how to request the token from the url and add the response to my stream. I’m not really a wizard at coding. Could you help me with this?

Comment: Sure. Are you familiar with how to do to HTTP requests on your platform?

Comment: No unfortunately not

Comment: I’m using android studio and java if it helps

Comment: Then you should probably start with this [Send a simple request](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple)

Comment: I tried this however I was unsure how to get my response and add it to my stream url.

Comment: You should learn how to Get and Send requests as it's the only way to achieve what you want in this case. The docs are the way to go

Comment: Ok thanks for the help. I’ll look into it and see what I find.